# Is it possible to get two sets of data with one query

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql, stored-procedures

I need to get some items from database with top three comments for each item.

Now I have two stored procedures `GetAllItems` and `GetTopThreeeCommentsByItemId`.

In application I get 100 items and then in foreach loop I call `GetTopThreeeCommentsByItemId` procedure to get top three comments.

I know that this is bad from performance standpoint.

Is there some technique that allows to get this with one query?

I can use `OUTER APPLY` to get one top comment (*if any*) but I don't know how to get three.

```
Items {ItemId, Title, Description, Price etc.}
Comments {CommentId, ItemId etc.}
```

Sample data that I want to get

- Item_1
  -- comment_1
  -- comment_2
  -- comment_3
- Item_2
  -- comment_4
  -- comment_5

Comment: please add table structures and sample data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One approach would be to use a CTE (Common Table Expression) if you're on SQL Server 2005 and newer (you aren't specific enough in that regard).

With this CTE, you can partition your data by some criteria - i.e. your `ItemId` - and have SQL Server number all your rows starting at 1 for each of those "partitions", ordered by some criteria.

So try something like this:

```
;WITH ItemsAndComments AS
(
   SELECT 
       i.ItemId, i.Title, i.Description, i.Price,
       c.CommentId, c.CommentText,
       ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY i.ItemId ORDER BY c.CommentId) AS 'RowNum'
   FROM 
       dbo.Items i
   LEFT OUTER JOIN 
       dbo.Comments c ON c.ItemId = i.ItemId
   WHERE
      ......
)
SELECT 
   ItemId, Title, Description, Price,
   CommentId, CommentText
FROM 
   ItemsAndComments
WHERE
   RowNum <= 3
```

Here, I am selecting up to three entries (i.e. comments) for each "partition" (i.e. for each item) - ordered by the `CommentId`.

Does that approach what you're looking for??

Comment: I use sql server 2008. With this I get three rows (for each comment). I thought that there is some way to get it in one row somehow. This means that on the ASP.NET side I need to check all rows for ItemId and add each comment to it's Item. Am I right?

Comment: @1110: you get **up to 3 rows** for each `item` - if that `item` has three or more comments. You get one row for each (`item/comment`) pair, so if one `item` has multiple `comment`s, the columns from the `Items` table are repeated - once for each comment.

Answer (score 0):

This gets two elder brother using OUTER APPLY:

```
select m.*, elder.*
from Member m
outer apply
(
 select top 2 ElderBirthDate = x.BirthDate, ElderFirstname = x.Firstname
 from Member x 
 where x.BirthDate < m.BirthDate 
 order by x.BirthDate desc
) as elder
order by m.BirthDate, elder.ElderBirthDate desc
```

Source data:

```
create table Member
(
 Firstname varchar(20) not null, 
 Lastname varchar(20) not null,
 BirthDate date not null unique
);

insert into Member(Firstname,Lastname,Birthdate) values
('John','Lennon','Oct 9, 1940'),
('Paul','McCartney','June 8, 1942'),
('George','Harrison','February 25, 1943'),
('Ringo','Starr','July 7, 1940');
```

Output:

```
Firstname            Lastname             BirthDate  ElderBirthDate ElderFirstname
-------------------- -------------------- ---------- -------------- --------------------
Ringo                Starr                1940-07-07 NULL           NULL
John                 Lennon               1940-10-09 1940-07-07     Ringo
Paul                 McCartney            1942-06-08 1940-10-09     John
Paul                 McCartney            1942-06-08 1940-07-07     Ringo
George               Harrison             1943-02-25 1942-06-08     Paul
George               Harrison             1943-02-25 1940-10-09     John

(6 row(s) affected)
```

Live test: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/19a63/2

[marc's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14030111/11432) is better, just use OUTER APPLY if you need to query "near" entities (e.g. geospatial, elder brothers, nearest date to due date, etc) to the main entity.

Outer apply walkthrough: http://www.ienablemuch.com/2012/04/outer-apply-walkthrough.html

You might need DENSE_RANK instead of ROW_NUMBER/RANK though, as the criteria of a comment being a top could yield ties. TOP 1 could yield more than one, TOP 3 could yield more than three too.  Example of that scenario(DENSE_RANK walkthrough): http://www.anicehumble.com/2012/03/postgresql-denserank.html

Comment: This is correct, but my God is this example confusing. There are no brothers in the example data and everyone in the example data is considered a brother of one another. This example would be much better with example data with 'real' family-relationships and an association table.

Comment: @Confusion I never thought they are confusing, I treat Beatles as brothers to each other though :-) If I put 'real' family-relationships, it would muddle up the logic of getting the top results for each entity, that would be more confusing

Answer (score 0):

You can write a single stored procedure which calls GetAllItems and GetTopThreeeCommentsByItemId, takes results in temp tables and join those tables to produce the single resultset you need.

If you do not have a chance to use a stored procedure, you can still do the same by running a single SQL script from data access tier, which calls GetAllItems and GetTopThreeeCommentsByItemId and takes results into temp tables and join them later to return a single resultset.

Answer (score 0):

Its better that you select the statement by using the row_number statement and select the top 3 alone

select a.* from 
(
Select *,row_number() over(partition by column)[dup]
) as a
where dup<=3